# Codeigniter products_model and products_images_model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, relation

i have two tables: Products with fields id, name, etc, and other table Products_images with fields id, id_product, file.

Is better one model considering table products_image is related only with products or two models, one from products and one from products_images.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are following the ORM. Then use separate models for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter is a very loosely designed framework that doesn't require you to follow strict guidelines.

My general rule of thumb is to always keep logic for different tables separate ( this is in line with the ORM approach). With that being said, if you feel that your models are dependent enough on each other, and share similar variables/methods then it may be a good idea to combine them; just make sure by combining them the structure doesn't get too confusing or the class doesn't get too long.